# How to auto-update an ordered lists numbering with vim? (Markdown file)

Tags: filetype-markdown

I use a plugin called bullet.vim. I am able to press `enter` and the numbered list increases from `1` too `2`. Normal stuff.

But if I have a list where I want to insert a new bullet between bullets, the numbered list does not auto-increment.

```markdown
1. 
2.    <---- press enter to insert new line here.
3.    
3.    <---- this remains as 3.
4.
```

How can I acheive auto updating numbered lists in markdown files?

Comment: The numbers are updated when you render it. E.g., even if you number all of them as 1, they will be properly incremented in the rendered text.

Comment: What do you mean by "when you render it"?

Comment: You say that you have a plugin for that so… let it handle the problem for you. If it doesn't, open an issue in their issue tracker.

Comment: @kadekai probably means that this is Markdown, a lightweight syntax for HTML. HTML is a document language that is rendered to be viewed as a document (this can be by a browser or other program). The Markdown spec requires that any sequence of numbered bullets is translated to a `<ol><li>…</li>…</ol>` (I think), so no matter what numbers your Markdown document uses, the rendered document will be in numeric order. Try `53241` and then convert the document to HTML/PDF/etc. and see what you get.

Comment: The way I usually deal with this is to renumber all the list items to `0`, and then use visual block mode to select the numbers (`<C-v>`) and then `g<C-a>` to increment them. It's not a great solution though. As mentioned, you don't *need* to have the numbers in order (just `1` for all items will do), but I like to make my Markdown documents read nicely both as Markdown and as HTML.